# How to post multiple photo in single tweet via twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

Is there any way to get uploaded image ID in twitter4j?
my problem is I want to use `setMediaIds(long[] ids)`. I'm uploading photo with this code:

```
ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUploadFactory(configuration).getInstance();
String result = imageUpload.upload("i", file[i].getInputstream());
```

How can I get uploaded photo Ids?

**I want to add multiple photos in single tweet via twitter4j**.

I know there are some related questions but those were for old version of twitter4j and this library has been updated recently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   //uploading multiple image 

   long[] mediaIds = new long[2];

   UploadedMedia media1 = twitter.uploadMedia(new File("image path here"));

   mediaIds[0] = media1.getMediaId();

   UploadedMedia media2 = twitter.uploadMedia(new File("image path here"));

   mediaIds[1] = media2.getMediaId();
   StatusUpdate update = new StatusUpdate("multi image upload---");
   update.setMediaIds(mediaIds);
   Status stat = twitter.updateStatus(update);
   System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + stat.getText() + "][" + stat.getId() + "]."); 



    //end of uploading multiple image
```

Comment: Please add explanations relevant to the question with your code in the future.